# MailHost: sending out email

Tags: plone

How one could do / where in Plone source code could be an example code for sending out MailHost emails

- Message payload is a text string, not template
- Sends out plaintext email, utf-8 encoded, both subject and message
- From: header is set correctly having both name and email address visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doc could help :

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/mailhost.securesend-is-now-deprecated-use-send-instead